# SSIS C# Script Task utf-16 to utf-8

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, ssis

Here is my current code:

```
    public void Main()
    {

        const string URL = @"mywebservice";

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.Timeout = 600000;
        HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;


        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string filePath = Dts.Variables["xmlFile"].Value.ToString();
        TextWriter file = new StreamWriter(filePath, false, Encoding.UTF8);
        using (file)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(xmlDeclaration);
            doc.Load(reader);
            doc.Save(file);
        }


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

The web service that I am trying to pull from is written in utf-16, and it needs to be in utf-8. I understand that my code may have some redundancies, but the current error that I have been receiving does not seem to pointing me in any sort of direction. Here is what my current error is. Any help would be appropriated, thanks.

> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object
>   obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>
> at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

Comment: I don't see an error in the stack trace that you posted.   Is there any more to it?

Comment: Unfortunately that is all that was in the stack. It stated "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."